# TagLib Sharp returning blank artist when mp3 has artist listed

Tags: c#, .net, id3, taglib-sharp

When retrieving the artist tag using TagLib Sharp, I've had some issues. Out of my 3000 or so songs, a few hundred had an empty string for the artist. However, in Windows Media Player and Windows Explorer (Under Contributing Artist), they have a listed artist. The following

```
TagLib.File f = TagLib.File.Create(filepath);
Console.WriteLine(f.Tag.Performers.Length);
Console.WriteLine(f.Tag.AlbumArtists.Length);
```

returns

```
0
0
```

Has anyone had this problem? I also tried using UltraID3, but the artist names were still blank.

Answer (score 4):

If you look at some of this 'few hundred songs' with a specialized tagging program like [Mp3tag](http://mp3tag.de/en/index.html), you should find the content and 'fields' which you see in WMP or Windows Explorer.

In this [tag mapping spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AoYQhIuWC-gcdHZwUDM3RGhneGMxSXpEX3pONXd6MWc&hl=en_US#gid=0) you will find a comparison of the tags. It shows how different they are named for various reasons. Maybe you will find your existing informations in Windows Media specific tags like the WM/AlbumArtist?